# Ionic Search Background color in IOS

Tags: css, ionic-framework, search, toolbar

I am using Ionic 3.2, and I am having problems with the Ionic searchbar's background color. The code is as follows:

```
</ion-navbar>
<ion-toolbar class="search-toolbar">
<ion-searchbar
[(ngModel)]="myInput"
[showCancelButton]="true"
(ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" (search)="searchByKeyword($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

It works just fine on Android, and it works on the Safari browser (on the Mac).
The problem starts when I run the application on my iPhone. The input background is not white. Instead it has the same color as the background outside the input bar, which is dark gray.

I already tried this:

```
.searchbar-md .searchbar-input 
{
    background: white !important;
}
```

The problem continues despite this change.

Is there a solution for this bug? I am on the verge of eliminating the searchbar from ios.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
.searchbar-ios .searchbar-input {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

The issue was solved by replacing < ion-toolbar class="search-toolbar" > 
with < div class="search-toolbar" >

It seems that in IOS < ion-toolbar > merges with other layers.

Answer (score 0):

You have trying to make an implementation only on the md mode which is Android mode just try to make the changes for the both modes md and ios.

```
.ion-searchbar .searchbar-input 
    {
        background: white !important;
        --background: white !important;
        background-color: white !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me, i added

```
ion-searchbar{
background: white !important;
--background: white !important;
background-color: white !important;
}
```

in  page.scss